# How to change the body background for three different div-s

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php file called shtype_porosine.php and also an external css file style.css. The php file I use to login to the web site and it has three different div tags. For the first one (div id="container_dyte") the body backgraound color must be white, but for the two others that are included include('include/administrator_index_nsp.php'); and include('include/login_forma.php'); the body color must be black.

I am not sure if a can use the body tag three times in the same php document, if so than the problem is solved (with body class="" i founded in the previous question "how-to-css-if-else-to-change-body-background-color"), but if not than which would be the solution?
Below is the code of the php file shtype_porosine.php

Thank you

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>website</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        session_start();
        // this is for an administrator
        if(isset($_SESSION['auser'])){
    ?>
    <div id="container_dyte">
        <span>Something here...</span>
    </div>
    <?php
    }else{
        // these is for a user
        if(isset($_SESSION['p_user'])){
            include('include/administrator_index_nsp.php');
        }else{
            // this is the login form to apear if fails the adminstrator and the user
            include('include/login_forma.php');
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `$_SESSION[ 'auser']` is set, if it is, make a body with a white `background-color`.

Otherwise make a body with a black `background-color`.

**Like this:**

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>website</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['auser'])){ ?>
    <body style='background-color:white'>
<?php } else { ?>
    <body style='background-color:black'>
 <?php }

        if(isset($_SESSION['auser'])){
    ?>
    <div id="container_dyte">
        <span>Something here...</span>
    </div>
    <?php
    }else{
        // these is for a user
        if(isset($_SESSION['p_user'])){
            include('include/administrator_index_nsp.php');
        }else{
            // this is the login form to apear if fails the adminstrator and the user
            include('include/login_forma.php');
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, your answer functions good, but it breaks the rules of a well constructed code. Everywhere I read, the php code must be inside the body tag of the html document and not outside of it.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned this is valid code, because PHP is a preprocessor for HTML, which is exactly what the code does. However, maybe it does break the rules of a well-constructed code, but your code doesn't look well-constructed by any means (you use no includes for the header, footer, content, etc.) This is not a big issue if you're the only one developing. As long as you understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body class="<?= isset($_SESSION['auser']) ? 'white' : 'black';?>">
<body style="background-color:<?= isset($_SESSION['auser']) ? 'white' : 'black';?>">
```

Comment: I added this block of code in the body part after the head tag, but i don't saw any changes. Thank you for your respond.

Comment: You're absolutely sure about that ? Yet session_start() must be put before any output.

Comment: First of all I think that your answer is the correct one but you should be more precise while adding it to my php file. I added your code again, but now after the session_start() declaration and I get the error: unexpected "<" in your first line of the code. I think the body tags of your code must be together with php -echo and in brackets or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change any "body". Just set the background-color css property for each of the div:

```
<div id="container_dyte" style="background-color:white">
```

In file  include/administrator_index_nsp.php

```
<div style="background-color:black">
```

In file  include/login_forma.php

```
<div style="background-color:black">
```

Comment: I am trying to change the body background not the div-s

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way:**
Give the divs diferent ID names and use CSS.

HTML

```
<div id="the_id">
```

CSS

```
#the_id {
    background-color:white;
}
```

**Medium way:**
Make a container div with a specyfic ID or CLASS and set up a CSS.

CSS

```
#container div { 
    background-color: black;
}
#container:first-child { 
    background-color: red;
}
#container:last-child { 
    background-color: white;
}
```

**Hard way:**
If you have a css specyfic for this page you can select the div number by style property.

```
body:nth-child(1) { background-color: black; };
body:nth-child(2) { background-color: red; };
body:nth-child(3) { background-color: white; };
```

If the css is ment for other pages do not use this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue, include a custom css, which will apply a required background color to the `<body>` tag. For example:

```
if (mode=='mode1')
{
   echo "<div id='div1'></div>";
   echo "<style type='text/css'> body { background-color:red } </style>";
}

if (mode=='mode2')
{
   echo "<div id='div2'></div>";
   echo "<style type='text/css'> body { background-color:yellow } </style>";
}

if (mode=='mode3')
{
   echo "<div id='div3'></div>";
   echo "<style type='text/css'> body { background-color:blue } </style>";
}
```

So using this logic, you can set the background color of the body, according to the divs showed